# solving differential equation 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

please help me to solve this differential equation :
$$
y'= \frac{x^2+3y^2}{2xy}
$$

I found this as answer but I'm not sure :
$$
\ln|x|=\ln\left| \frac{y^2}{x^2}+1\right|+c
$$

Comment: Hint:let $\dfrac{y}{x}=u$,

Comment: I found that letting $u=y^2/x^3$ helps.

Comment: in fact , in my solution as math110 said I did took $t=\dfrac{y}{x}$ ...

Comment: @RonGordon You mean $ u = (y/x)^2 ?$

Comment: no I mean $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$ and then $u^{2}=\dfrac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}$

Comment: @Narasimham: see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite as

$$y y' = \frac12 (y^2)' = \frac12 x + \frac {3 y^2}{2 x} $$

Let $v=y^2$.  Then

$$v' = x + \frac{3 v}{x} \implies x^3 v' - 3 x^2 v = x^4 \implies \frac{x^3 v' - 3 x^2 v }{x^6} = \frac1{x^2} $$

or

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left (\frac{v}{x^3} \right ) = \frac1{x^2}$$

which means that

$$\frac{y^2}{x^3} = C - \frac1{x} $$

etc. etc.

Comment: thanks for solution but you can simply take $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$ and then set it on this homogenous equation $\int \dfrac{dx}{x} = \int \dfrac{du}{f(u)-u}$

Comment: @sajjad: would you like to demonstrate?  I disagree.  (e.g., what is $f$?)  And please point out where I steered you wrong.

Comment: this equation  $\int \dfrac{dx}{x} = \int \dfrac{du}{f(u)-u}$ is what they thought me on collage for homogenous differential equation but your way to answer is something that I didn't see until now

Comment: @RonGordon. Cool, it was n't immediately obvious.

Comment: @sajjad: actually, the answer you saw is correct.  My answer is another expression of that answer.

Comment: yes that's absolutely right..it seems like your answer is a little bit complicated....

Comment: @sajjad: I completely disagree, but that is subjective of course.  The result is the same, and my method uses nothing more than the quotient rule.  The other answer is derived using a lot of intermediate stuff that cancels, and I feel that ends up being more complicated.

Comment: also excuse me I missed to answer your question above $f(u)$ is the same $f(x)$ but where we changed $y$'s to $u$'s by dividing whole to $x^{2}$